# AWS ELB - Target group Healthy but not accessible

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-elb, aws-alb

I have two different accounts:

One in Europe eu-central-1: Have the Route53 DNS entries from domain

Another in China cn-north-1: Have the ALB resource and the EC2 resource.

In China, my service is a concourse pipeline. The service is up and running on the instance, and on the target groups I can see the healthy flag. At the instance as well I can access the web page by curl localhost:8080.

I have the entry:
`concourse.domain.name    CNAME web.account.info.eu-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com`

I Can resolve the entry and it's point to the right alb. But still, no answer.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There would be 2 steps to follow to find the route case.

If your ALB public DNS name is working and routing traffic to your instance then please check the value of the "Hosted zone" in the property of ALB and Route 53 match.

If your ALB does not routing traffic make sure your have set up Listener for each traffic type (http,https...ect) which your application is about to listen to and also have target group for perspective port(80,8080...)for each listener traffic type.
Make sure each target group has at least one instance to handle each type of traffic on each port.

Hope this was helpful

Comment: Hello Sumanth, thanks for your answer. Yes, there is a Hosted Zone ID, but in the chinese account there is no route53 hosted zone. And it's different from the one that is in the European account. 

The target groups are created, and there's only a available port that is 8080, no ACM or something that could make it difficult.

Comment: The ID in there is Z1GDH35T77C1KE the same represented in the AWS documentation.
Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/elb.html

Comment: @PatrickReisdeSouza please try and use Alias which points to your ALB name in place of CNAME.

Comment: Still, no answer.